# Android app failed to insert entries into database

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, database

I am trying to insert entries into database from android app and php mysql. I tried tutorials ,google and stack overflow but it's still not working. First i am getting data from form user filled form in android app.

```
   public class Sending_Data_To_Server extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
        String First_Name,Last_Name,Phone,Mail_ID,Password;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            First_Name=params[0];
            Last_Name=params[1];
            Phone=params[2];
            Mail_ID=params[3];
            Password=params[4];
            Log.d("SEND DATA VALUES",First_Name+Last_Name+Phone);
            //LOG SHOWS VALES COMING AS FILLED IN ABOVE CODE


            String Link="http://www.boysjoys.com/test/Android/Data/showData.php?";
            try {

                String data= URLEncoder.encode("First_Name","UTF-8")+ "=" +URLEncoder.encode(First_Name,"UTF-8");        
                data+= "&" +URLEncoder.encode("Last_Name","UTF-8")+ "=" +URLEncoder.encode(Last_Name,"UTF-8");
                data+= "&" + URLEncoder.encode("Phone","UTF-8")+ "=" +URLEncoder.encode(Phone,"UTF-8");
                data+= "&" + URLEncoder.encode("Mail_ID","UTF-8")+ "=" +URLEncoder.encode(Mail_ID,"UTF-8");
                data+= "&" + URLEncoder.encode("Password","UTF-8")+ "=" +URLEncoder.encode(Password,"UTF-8");

                Log.d("SEND CLASS---------",data);
                //DATA VARIABLE IN LOG SHOWS IT GETTING ALL VALUES AS FILLED


                URL url=new URL(Link+data);
                HttpURLConnection con= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();



                /***************This Block I Also Tried to send data to server
    URLConnection connection=url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStreamWriter writer= new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
                writer.write(data);
                Log.d("SEND DATA","----WRITING DATA TO SERVER");
                writer.flush();
    **************************/

                BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader((new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream())));
                String result=reader.readLine();
                return result;


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }        
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);

        }

    }
```

Then my PHP MYSQl code (i think this has some problem) where i m trying to insert entries into database which is sent by app.

```
<?php
    $host='localhost';
$uname='root';
$pass='pass';
$db='App';

$con=mysqli_connect($host,$uname,$pass,$db);

$First_Name=$_POST['First_Name'];
$Last_Name=$_POST['Last_Name'];
$Phone=$_POST['Phone'];
$Mail_ID=$_POST['Mail_ID'];
$Password =$_POST['Password'];
$La=$_POST['La'];
$Lo=$_POST['Lo'];
$Ac=$_POST['Ac'];
$Pro=$_POST['Pro'];

$sql="INSERT INTO mobile_App(First_Name,Last_Name,Phone,Mail_ID,Password,La,Lo,Ac,Pro)
VALUES ('$First_Name,$Last_Name,$Phone,$Mail_ID,$Password,$La,$Lo,$Ac,$Pro')";

if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
echo 'Data Inserted Successfully';
}
else{
echo 'Try Again';

}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Here is my Database Table Structure [Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPAe8.png)

Comment: Please dont down vote i really need help

Comment: and what is the value you r getting.. 0 or 1.. or anythng else..??

Comment: In server side i m getting error {"query_result":"FAILED"} 1 
1 is value returned ID from database.You can check by yourself by visiting this link

http://www.boysjoys.com/test/Android/Data/showData.php

Comment: why don't you print the query.. like `echo "INSERT INTO mobile_App (First_Name,Last_Name,Phone,Mail_ID,Password)
VALUES ('$First_Name,$Last_Name,$Phone,$Mail_ID,$Passwordr')";` and run it on php my admin.you will see why query failed.

Comment: and why ( ` ) mark here.. `('$First_Name,$Last_Name,$Phone,$Mail_ID,$Passwordr')`

Comment: I did but its still showing query failed and that (') mark is values to insert
its not long code but its taking too much time to resolve please help me guys

Answer (score 0):

if i am not wrong.. this is the link..

> String Link="http://www.boysjoys.com/test/Android/Data/showData.php?";

how can it connect the database as.. localhost.(i mean its live database link http://www)

```
 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","User","Pass","FinalApp");
```

check your database credentials.

Comment: its on server and its live database.As you can see i am also getting last database ID as return.So that means its connected. but i still not get what am  missing in code to work it.